# Tab indicator's selected tab not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have these tabs in Compose in which if I click on the second tab I need the color of the selected tab to change to that one but it doesn't, the first tab stays selected even though I can see the contents of the second tab. I'm not sure why this is happening, it seems like the selected index is updated to 1 but then it loads again and it goes back to 0 so the 1rst tab stays selected.
I can tell tell the issue is the viewmodel, if I don't load anything then the tabs works well or if I only load the data for the first tab but if I also want to load data on the second tab then this happens.

This is the code:

```
        val indicatorOffset = remember(selectedItemIndex) {
            selectedItemIndex * tabWidth.value
        }

        MyTabIndicator(
            indicatorWidth = tabWidth,
            indicatorOffset = indicatorOffset.dp,
            indicatorColor = MyColor(),
        )
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            items.mapIndexed { index, text ->
                val isSelected = index == selectedItemIndex
                TabItem(
                    isSelected = isSelected,
                    onClick = {
                        onClick(index)
                    },
                    tabWidth = tabWidth,
                    text = text
                )
            }
        }
```

I use it like this:

```
                val (selected, setSelected) = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(0)
                }

                TabsComponent(
                    items = listOf(
                        "1st tab",
                        "2nd tab"
                    ),
                    selectedItemIndex = selected,
                    onClick = { index ->
                        setSelected(index)
                        when (index) {
                            0 -> {
                                viewModel.load2()
                            }
                            1 -> {
                                viewModel.load2()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
```